# Limit using Big O notation, incorrect use?

Tags: analysis

I'm wondering if $\lim_{k\to\infty} (\frac{1}{k^2} + O(\frac{1}{k^4}))^{\frac{1}{k}}$ can be calculated in the following manner:

$\lim_{k\to\infty}(\frac{1}{k^2} + O(\frac{1}{k^4}))^{\frac{1}{k}} = \lim_{k\to\infty}(\frac{1}{k^2}(1 + O(\frac{1}{k^2}))^{\frac{1}{k}} = $ {for 
 k > 0} $ = \lim_{k\to\infty} (e ^{-2 \cdot ln k \cdot \frac{1}{k}}(1 + O(\frac{1}{k^2}))^{1/k} )= 1 * 1$

My concerns lie in the second to last and last step due to the error term being of the same magnitude as other components which appear in the limit.

Answer (score 0):

May I confess first that, in spite of my passion for the composition of Taylor series, I never felt very comfortable with this kind of question.

So, for what it is worth, I tell you my working

$$y=\left(\frac{1}{k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right) \right)^{\frac 1 k}$$
$$\log(y)={\frac 1 k}\log\left(\frac{1}{k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right) \right)={\frac 1 k}\left(-2 \log \left({k}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\right)=-2\frac{\log(k)}k+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=1-2\frac{ \log \left({k}\right)}{k}+2\frac{ \log
   ^2\left({k}\right)}{k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$ In fact I suppose that this should write
$$y=1-2\frac{ \log \left({k}\right)}{k}+O\left(\frac{ \log
   ^2\left({k}\right)}{k^2}\right)$$